# Sufficient and necessary condition for a function to be holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ defined in a neighborhood of $z_0=x_0+iy_0$. $u,v$ are differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$ and they follow Cauchy-Riemann equations $\iff$ $f(z)$ is differentiable at $z_0$

Is the following statement is correct? (sorry for the wording, it was translated)

Comment: I think it should be that $u,v \in C^1$ for this to be true.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Goursat.27s_theorem_and_its_generalizations gives various conditions.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. But be well aware that differentiability of $u$ and $v$ means Fréchet differentiability. Mere partial differentiability is not enough.